# Terminate background job and its children on exit

Tags: bash

The main script has a background task executing test1.sh, i am trying to stop the background task when the main task also completes

```
#!/bin/sh

# background process

./test1.sh &

# do while starts

x=1
while [ $x -le 30 ]
do
  echo "Welcome $x times "
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
  sleep 1
done

exit
```

The ./test1.sh file contains

```
#!/bin/sh

while true
do
    echo "copying "
    cp logs.txt /tmp
    sleep 10
done
```

Or any best approach to run the background task in a separate thread of copying files and exit after the main task completes

Comment: Do you want to terminate `cp`/`sleep` too?

Comment: You can add a command to kill background task's PID just before the main thread completes.

Comment: @oguzismail yes both

Comment: @LohitGupta I tried, but I get an error message like No such process

Comment: @oguzismail can you the complete example please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable job control temporarily to put the background job into a separate process group, and set an EXIT trap in the main shell to broadcast a TERM signal to the background job and its children on exit.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -m
./test1.sh &
set +m

trap "kill -- -$!" EXIT

# rest of the program
```

Answer (score 0):

The background process PID can be accessed by assigning it to a variable with $! and then calling it later. See below:

```
#!/bin/sh

# background process

./test1.sh &

# set $test1_pid to the PID of ./test1.sh & (Presumed BG [1])
test1_pid=$!

# do while starts

x=1
while [ $x -le 30 ]
do
  echo "Welcome $x times "
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
  sleep 1
done

# Terminate BG process
kill $test1_pid

exit
```

Comment: That doesn't kill cp and sleep.

Comment: Yes, this won't kill cp and sleep

Comment: Failure to read the comments on my part. I was drawing on the assumption that the background process was the only one desired to be killed. Good answer, @oguzismail Thanks for pointing that out.